# Spring Neo4j @Query not populating related entities until a subsequent .findOne called

Tags: graph, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following Cypher which is working correctly in the Neo4j browser and returning all related entities as expected:

```
MATCH (cmp:Competition)-[:COMPETITION_COUNTRY]-(cc:Country)
WHERE ID(cmp)=16860

MATCH (cmp)-[:COMPETITION]-(s:Season)<-[:SEASON]-(f:Fixture)
WHERE s.yearStart=2019

MATCH (f)-[:HOME_TEAM]-(ht:Team)-[:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(htc:Country)
MATCH (f)-[:HOME_TEAM]-(at:Team)-[:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(atc:Country)

RETURN cmp, s, f, ht, at, htc, atc
ORDER BY f.matchDate DESC, ht.name DESC
```

And I have this as a `Neo4jRepository` function as follows:

```
@Query("MATCH (cmp:Competition)-[:COMPETITION_COUNTRY]-(cc:Country)\n" +
        "WHERE ID(cmp)={0}\n" +
        "\n" +
        "MATCH (cmp)-[:COMPETITION]-(s:Season)<-[:SEASON]-(f:Fixture)\n" +
        "WHERE s.yearStart={1}\n" +
        "\n" +
        "MATCH (f)-[:HOME_TEAM]-(ht:Team)-[:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(htc:Country)\n" +
        "MATCH (f)-[:HOME_TEAM]-(at:Team)-[:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(atc:Country)\n" +
        "\n" +
        "RETURN cmp, s, f, ht, at, htc, atc\n" +
        "ORDER BY f.matchDate DESC, ht.name DESC"
)
List<Fixture> getCompetitionYearFixtures(
         Long competitionId, Integer yearStart
);
```

I call this method as follows:

```
List<Fixture> fixtures =
        fixtureRepository
                .getCompetitionYearFixtures(
                        competitionId, year);
```

Although all the expected `Fixture`s are returned, none of the related entities are populated:
[image: Unpopulated Fixtures]

However, I discovered that if I immediately run the following statement for any one (and only one) of the returned `Fxture`s, then every `Fixture` in `fixture`s is suddenly fully populated:

```
fixtureRepository.findOne(fixtures.get(0).getId(), 3);
```

As so:
[image: Populated Fixtures]

So my question is, is there a way of returning the `Fixture`s with all related entities populated after the first trip to the database, without having to go back?

I specifically retrieved everything I needed in the Cypher, and the idea of using a `depth` of 3 in the `findOne` is something I'm a little uncomfortable with as in future I may add new relations which I won't necessarily want bloating the query.

---

**EDIT**
Solution, with thanks to František Hartman:

```
MATCH r1=(cmp:Competition)-[cmp_c:COMPETITION_COUNTRY]-(cmpc:Country)
WHERE ID(cmp)=16860
MATCH r2=(cmp)-[cmp_s:COMPETITION]-(s:Season)<-[s_f:SEASON]-(f:Fixture)
WHERE s.yearStart=2019
MATCH r3=(f)-[f_ht:HOME_TEAM]-(ht:Team)-[ht_c:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(htc:Country)
MATCH r4=(f)-[f_at:AWAY_TEAM]-(at:Team)-[at_c:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(atc:Country)
RETURN r1,r2,r3,r4
ORDER BY f.matchDate DESC,ht.name DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return everything that you want to map, in your case you are expecting the relationships to be mapped as well (even if you don't have relationship entities, the relationship says e.g. the fixture and home team are related).

To see what is exactly returned in your Neo4j browser go to "Browser settings" (cog icon left bottom) -> Uncheck "Connect result nodes"

You query with relationships (you might be able to come up with better names then r1-r7):

```
MATCH (cmp:Competition)-[r1:COMPETITION_COUNTRY]-(cc:Country)
WHERE ID(cmp)=16860

MATCH (cmp)-[r2:COMPETITION]-(s:Season)<-[r3:SEASON]-(f:Fixture)
WHERE s.yearStart=2019

MATCH (f)-[r4:HOME_TEAM]-(ht:Team)-[r5:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(htc:Country)
MATCH (f)-[r6:HOME_TEAM]-(at:Team)-[r7:TEAM_COUNTRY]-(atc:Country)

RETURN cmp, s, f, ht, at, htc, atc, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7
ORDER BY f.matchDate DESC, ht.name DESC
```

The `findOne` method (with depth parameter 3) loads everything, including the relationships up to 3 steps, which will be populated into cached instances of your data.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. It seems so obvious now you've explained, but Neo4j browser filling in the relationships is what was really confusing me, so I'm glad I know about that checkbox now.